# Regex to match square bracket url

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to parse urls from in this format `[urlTextHere](http://link.to/url/text)`

I'm having trouble matching with the pattern, I am able to match either `[]`or `()` but not both.

How to match both, and retrieve as separate strings?

Comment: [`(\[.*?])(\(.*?\))`](https://regex101.com/r/XrfvAa/1)

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

To match them both including the `[]` and `()`, you could capture them in 2 groups including them:

[`(\[[^\]]+\])(\([^)]+\))`](https://regex101.com/r/SoB1pd/1)

That would match

- Capture in a group `(`
- Match [ `\[`
- Match not ] `[^\]]+` one or more times
- Match ] `\]`
- Close capture group `)`

Then use this mechanism as well for the `()`

To match what is inside `[]` and `()`, you could capture them in 2 groups excluding them:

[`\[([^\]]+)\]\(([^)]+)\)/)`](https://regex101.com/r/SoB1pd/2)

```js
var str = "[urlTextHere](http://link.to/url/text)";
console.log(str.match(/(\[[^\]]+\])(\([^)]+\))/));
console.log(str.match(/\[([^\]]+)\]\(([^)]+)\)/));
```